# Get post count for current custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

My site has a custom taxonomy called `series`. Underneath each post, I'm trying to display a specific div, but only if that post is in a series, and only if that series has more than one post. I feel like this should be possible with a simple if-statement, but I'm not sure how to evaluate the post count of the current post's first (because technically speaking one post could be in multiple series) `series` taxonomy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'series' )` to obtain all terms associated with the current post. This function returns array of `WP_Term` objects and `WP_Term` has `count` property which can be used as condition.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried the following:

`$allseries = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'series');
    $firstseries = $allseries[0];
    if ( $allseries['count'] > 0 ) {
     echo 'something';
    }`

But no luck so far. I'm very rusty in PHP, so any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: `count` is property of `WP_Term` so you'd need to check eg. `if ( $firstseries->count > 0 )` as `$allseries` is an array.